# Git : How to restrict tag push

Tags: version-control

Is there any way to restrict people from pushing tags in git repository ? In bitbucket under "branch management" there is an option to allow branch access , but by disabling it even code push is failing. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You may write some git update hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $USER != "git-repo-admin" ];
then
  if [ "$1" == refs/tags/* ];
  then
    echo "Tag push is restricted"
    exit 1
  fi
fi
```